# subfloat: how to position label to the left?

Tags: subfloats, labels

How can I make `\subfloat` put the labels to the left of the images? It seems it only supports "top" and "bottom". I am searching for a solution without using `\tabular`.
Thanks and regards, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top}   % "position=left" is not supported!!! :(
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}
\vfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output (in red the location I'd like to achieve):

[image]

Comment: What's the problem with `tabular`? By the way, `\vfill` will do nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for the observation! P.S. Nothing wrong about `\tabular`; just looking for an alternative solution :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

it is obtained by use of the environment `\sidesubfloat` from the package `floatrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[label font=bf]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=center}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck}}

\medskip
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-duck}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Follow up: how can I tweak the space between the labels and the figures? I got lost trying to understand the (quite lengthy!) `floatrow` documentation :(

Comment: @dontpanic, well, i also need to check documentation. i doubt that i will more successful than you. try to search on site. i will return to your question later.

Comment: OK, thanks. I've searched the forum and found some clues, but not a direct answer. I was trying (without luck) to use the following in the header:  `\newlength\mysep
\setlength\mysep{1cm}
\DeclareFloatSeparators{mysep}{\hskip\mysep}
`   `\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top,capbesidesep=mysep}`